# How to count number of files using a batch script and subfiles in several folders for example home folders on a server

Tags: windows, batch-file, count

In an example to use this to give number of files completely held including all subfolders of each users area in a home directory listing. I have found ways to read the file structure into a txt file.

user1 has 20 files spread in several sub directories in his home area. I am not interested in actual listing of sub folders and file count within, which I have seen the answer to but I cannot modify the script due to my lack of  knowledge
So in this example - home directory has 99 users from user1 to user99 each having various sub folders etc

SO to give an output as follows into a .txt file which could be placed into a spreadsheet.

```
Username # number of files
user1 # 20
user2 # 34
user3 # 93
user99 # 4
```

and so on - double line spacing purely to get each result output on one line which I cant seem to do with this editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FOR /D` to iterate the users within a root folder. I'll use "C:\USERS\" as the root. Note: You may need to run within a console having admin privileges.

For each user, use `DIR` piped to `FIND` to count the number of files. The `DIR /A-D` option lists files only, including hidden and system files. The `/B` option lists files only, without any header or summary info. The `/S` option includes subdirectories. The `FIND /C` option counts the matches, and `/V ""` is an odd feature that matches all lines.

From the command line:

```
for /d %U in (*) do @for /f %C in ('dir /s /b /a-d "%U"^|find /c /v ""') do @echo %U # %C
```

With a batch script

```
@echo off
for /d %%U in (*) do for /f %%C in ('dir /s /b /a-d "%%U"^|find /c /v ""') do echo %%U # %%C
```

Comment: Thanks, that appears to work perfectly well, and great explanation which is appreciated, next to try on a server and this looks like will save me some time rather than processing this manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "cmd=dir user1 /s /b | find /C ":""

for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set number=%%a
echo user1 # %number%
```

Comment: That only processes a single user, and it mistakenly includes folders in the count.